# How Bind Child Control To A View Object (Like PageCollectionView) In Master\Detail scenario With MVVM In SILVERLIGHT

Tags: silverlight

I have a question about “Master\Detail” data binding using MVVM and I hope you can help me with it:

Let say my Master ModelView is “ProductModelView” (for Product Entity) and the Product Entity has a property named ProductInventories of type Entity Collection. I defined a “DomainCollectionView” in my master  ProductModelView with name: “ProductViewDCV”

I do following items to fill my master and details Datagrids:

1-Set the DataContext of my page to my ModelView : ProductModelView

2-Bind master Datagrid (name: masterDG) to ProductViewDCV.

3-Bind detail Datagrid (name: detailDG) to ProductInventories property of my master ProductViewDCV :

```
<sdk:DataGrid x:Name=" detailDG " 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path= ProductViewDCV. ProductInventories }"/>
```

The Program works well ,As I change the row in master DataGrid , The current item in the child DataGrid also changes.

But my question and Problem :

1. When I bind my detail (child) DataGrid as mentioned in step 3 , the child DataGrid is bound to “EntityCollection” not a View Object Like “PagedCollectionView” or “DomainCollectionView” ,So I can’t use benefits like Sorting ,Grouping and Paging on my child (detail) DataGrid. I want to know :How I can bind my child DataGrid to a View Object in MVVM pattern to use Paging  option.(Namely I want to have Paging and Grouping Options in my child DataGrid.)

### Look forward to receiving your reply.

Hello.

I really appreciate your kind and quick answer. I did as you said ,but I encounter a problem and I hope you help me:

**Method:**

In my “**ProductModelView**” (for Product Entity) I defined following objects:

**1**-private **DomainCollectionView** **_ProductViewDCV**; (As Master(Parent) View)

**2**-private **PagedCollectionView** **_ProductViewPCV**; (As Detail(Child) View)

**3**-In Constructor of  “ProductModelView” class, I assigned an EVentHandler to “_ ProductViewDCV”(my DomainCollectionView as Master view):

```
this._ProductViewDCV.CurrentChanged+=_ProductViewDCV_CurrentChanged;

this._ProductViewDCV.Refresh();
```

**4**-In the EventHandler , I Create a new “**PagedCollectionView**” (my Detail/Child view) and assign it to my  _ProductViewDCV :

```
if (_ProductViewDCV.CurrentItem != null)

{ 

_ProductViewPCV = new PagedCollectionView((_ProductViewDCV.CurrentItem as BA1.Web.Product).ProductInventories);

//ProductViewPCV.Refersh();

 }
```

**5**-In my View File (XAML file), I have two Datagrids which are configured as follow :

```
Page DataContext is set to an object of my ModelView : ProductViewModel
sdk:DataGrid x:Name="dgParent"   Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProductViewDCV}"//my Master/Parent DataGrid

sdk:DataGrid Grid.Row="2" x:Name="dgDetails"   ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProductViewPCV}//My Detail/Child DataGrid
```

**Problem :**

When I change the current row in my Master/Parent DataGrid , nothing happens in Detail/Child DataGrid and testing  the Detail/Child DataGrid’s Itemssource property , returns “Null” ,not an object of “PagedCollectionview”.

Where’s my problem and why doesn’t the Detail/Child DataGrid get updated in response to Master/Parent current item changing? (Testing shows that ProductViewPCV itself changes when it’s parent collection changes.)

Again let me thank you for giving me advices on this problem.

Comment: I'm a bit rusty with Silverlight now, but I suspect that you will have to expose the child collection from your view model as a PagedCollectionView, and populate this when the current item on the parent collection view changes.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, there's a few problems I can see.  You should instantiate the _ProductViewPCV PagedCollectionView property in the constructor, and not create new instances of it in the _ProductViewDCV_CurrentChanged event handler.  If you did want to do this, then you need to notify the view that the value of this _ProductViewPCV property has changed by raising a PropertyChanged event.  However, you shouldn't do this as it's likely to result in a memory leak.

You'd be best off wrapping an observable collection in the PagedCollectionView, and simply updating the contents of the observable collection in the _ProductViewDCV_CurrentChanged event handler I think.  The view should update automatically I think.  Sorry, I'm a little rusty on this, but I think that should work for you.